# Javascript blocked in SharePoint 2016 document libraries?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, document-library

I've developed a small application using html, css, and javascript and have placed the files in a document library on my company's SharePoint site for my team to access. Users just go to the url of index.html and the paths to the css and js files are relative so everything works fine. The reason I am using SharePoint to serve the files is to piggyback off of the permissioning so I can limit access to only certain User Groups in the company.

However the company is upgrading to SharePoint 2016 and the developer working on the project is telling me I need to find another solution because SharePoint 2016 won't serve my javascript files to the browser. I'm pretty skeptical as when I looked at the Office support site .js isn't one of the six file extensions that are blocked in 2016 (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Types-of-files-that-cannot-be-added-to-a-list-or-library-30be234d-e551-4c2a-8de8-f8546ffbf5b3). He keeps referring to my application as "custom code". I've tried to make it clear to him that the application uses zero SharePoint code...but he still insists it will not work with SharePoint 2016.

I can't find anything online that confirms our developer's statements. Could you kindly share your understanding of this? Is it true that 2016 won't allow javascript files to be served to a user's browser when accessed via a document library?

Comment: Better place to ask: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/